# Use Custom Defined repository as CRUD implementation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I have developed an springboot application using mongo and redis.

I have used following annotation to enable Redis Repository and its working fine

```
@EnableRedisRepositories(basePackages = {"com.foo.something"})
```

But Now I have implemented a custom CRUD repository as below

```
public abstract class RedisCrudRepositoryImpl<T, ID> implements CrudRepository<T, ID> {


  private RedisMappingContext mappingContext;
  @Autowired
  private StringRedisTemplate template;
  private RedisConverter converter;
  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
  @Autowired
  private RedisCustomConversions customConversions;
  private EntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation;
```

My Repository class looks like this

```
public interface BaseProductRepository extends CrudRepository<BaseProduct, String> {
```

Now byDefault Redis will its own implementation i.e. KeyValueRepository but i want to use my custom repository as an implementation to CrudRepository

I don't want to change `public interface BaseProductRepository extends CrudRepository` to

```
public class BaseProductRepository extends RedisCrudRepositoryImpl
```

Extension should still remain CrudRepository but implementation should be RedisCrudRepositoryImpl

Answer (score 0):

I may not be able to help with a direct solution to your problem. However, Spring does allow you to implement your own base repository and use it as implementation for other repositories.
Refer [Spring Data Common 2.2.6](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference) section 4.6

The documentation may vary for the version you are using.